# $E(V −\mu) = 0$ Is this is a definition?

Tags: probability, expectation

> $V$ has a probability mass function.
>   \begin{align} p_V (0) &= 0.5 \\ p_V (1) &= 0.3 \\ p_V (2) &= 0.2 \end{align}
>   Find $E(V −\mu) $

The textbook gives the answer $0$ but no working. Is this a standard definition?

I know $ E(V) = \mu $ but it's confusing as it is contained within the function (within the brackets) of expectation.

Comment: It's useful to see how the standard measures change under simple operations.  $E[aV+b]=aE[V]+b$, $Var[aV+b]=a^2Var[V]$ for real numbers $a,b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you know that

$$
\mu = E[V]
$$
By linearity of expectation you have 
$$
E[V - \mu] = E[V] - E[\mu] = \mu - \mu = 0
$$

---

If you want the details of the underlying computation :
$$\mu = 0\cdot 0.5 + 1\cdot 0.3 + 2\cdot 0.2 = 0.7$$

Now define $Y = V-\mu = V-0.7$ hence $Y$ takes now values in $\{-0.7,0.3,1.3 \}$. The probabilities of $Y$ haven't changed. Only the value that $Y$ can take :
$$
\begin{cases}
P_Y(-0.7) = 0.5 \\
P_Y(0.3) = 0.3 \\
P_Y(1.3) = 0.2
\end{cases}
$$
Now computing the expectation of $Y$ we have :
$$
E[V - \mu] = E[Y] = -0.7 \cdot 0.5 + 0.3 \cdot 0.3 + 1.3 \cdot 0.2 = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you. Very clear explanation